# Finding orphaned files in ESX 6.0

Tags: vmware, esxi

Do you know of any way to scan an ESX datastore to help identify Orphaned files, or provide a graphical representation of the file types and sizes in use?

Browsing through the datastore, I was able to identify a 600GB vmdk file that wasn't in use by any virtual server.  I verified the vmdk wasn't in use, by checking the server's disk settings and finding that the vmdk file wasn't listed there.

I found this one, and I suspect there may be others.

Is there any easy way to identify orphaned files on ESX 6.0 without manually identifying them myself?  If there were a tool that read through all the vmx files and compared that against vmdk files to identify orphans, that would be a huge help to us.  Is there a more efficient way to go about finding large files that are not in use?

Answer (score 0):

RVTools is a free tool which can be used to identify Orphaned VMDKs.

https://www.robware.net/rvtools/

After installing the software, when you launch the tool, it will ask you for credentials and the address of your vSphere server.  After providing valid information, the tool opened, and I clicked on the vHealth tab.

On the vHealth tab were two files that were identified as possible zombie VMs.